# How to enable directory browsiing in IIS7?

Tags: iis, iis-7

How I enable directory browsing in IIS7?

MS technet says this can be done in the IIS console:

> 1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage.
> 2. In Features View, double-click Directory Browsing.
> 3. In the Actions pane, click Enable if the Directory Browsing
>      feature is disabled and you want to
>      enable it. Or, click Disable if the
>      Directory Browsing feature is enabled
>      and you want to disable it.
>
> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28WS.10%29.aspx

However, my IIS console doesn't have the **Directory Browsing** option mentioned in Step 2.

How can this option be made available.

Note, this is for a static HTML site, so I don't have any web.config or ASPX files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because 'Directory Browsing' is one of the Role services you have to specifically install. You do that from Server Manager -> Roles -> Web Services -> Add Role Services. Pick 'Directory Browsing' in the wizard. Then you should have the options specified in the KB article.

Answer (score 5):

This is in case anyone needs help:

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. turn on off windows features
3. ***Select Internet Information Services***
4. Select World Wide Web Services
5. Common HTTP Features
6. Select Directory Browsing

Answer (score 4):

And for the command line nerds out there, to do this without the GUIs:

```
servermanagercmd -install Web-Dir-Browsing
appcmd set config (url) /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

where (url) is the name of your web site and optional path to virtual directory, like "Default Web Site/Pictures". You can list web sites by typing

```
appcmd list site
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Features View... click on your site, look under "IIS" - where it has authentication, MIME Types, Compression etc.

There should be a Directory Browsing icon, it's where I located mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this with powershell

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/directoryBrowse -name enabled -value true -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\xxx'
```